# About Accessibility of the diagram

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I am using cytoscape package for diagram purpose and trying to access or select nodes and links in the diagram by keyboard. I could not find documentation about keys.
Would you please point me accessibility document of cytoscape diagram package?

Answer (score 1):

Cytoscape.js does not handle keyboard events. You have to use the standard DOM API functions for this:

```
document.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {
  const keyName = event.key;

  // As the user releases the Ctrl key, the key is no longer active,
  // so event.ctrlKey is false.
  if (keyName === 'Control') {
    alert('Control key was released');
  }
}, false);
```